# How to make a Trigger to populate table automatically based on a value in another table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I made a trigger that automatically populates a table from my database.

This trigger populates the alarm table and runs in the table registos. 
The trigger performs a check to lim_inf_temp field sensors table, and if the value of the temperature records of the table is less than the value of the table lim_inf_temp sensors fills the table fields alarms.

Only the way the trigger is taken the lim_inf_temp is always the same, and does not vary depending on the idSensor. Does anyone could help me complete / improve my trigger please.

I hope I have explained my doubts the best way. 
If someone did not realize I try to explain otherwise.

Thank you all.

---

[image]

---

Trigger that I do

```
CREATE TRIGGER Alert ON registos AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @comp decimal= 0
DECLARE @tempmin decimal= 0


DECLARE @current_max_idAlarme int = (SELECT MAX(IdAlarme) FROM alarmes)
DECLARE @temp decimal = (SELECT lim_inf_temp  from sensores where idSensor=idSensor )


-- Insert into alarmes from the inserted rows if temperature less than tempmin
INSERT alarmes (IdAlarme, descricao_alarme,data_criacao, idRegisto)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.idRegisto) + @current_max_idAlarme,
    'temp Error', GETDATE(),
    i.idRegisto
FROM
    inserted AS i
WHERE
    i.Temperatura < @temp

END
```

---

But like i said this comparison is wrong because it compares registos.temperatura always with the same value of sensores.lim_inf_temp. And that's not what I want. Want it to be in accordance with the same sensores.idSensor and registos.idSensor.

One again thanks for your help.

--------------EDIT QUESTION-----------------

Solved the problem described above. I would like to edit the trigger in order to add fields from two different tables. 
The inserts I would like to add are as follows, however I have no idea how to add them. I've done this trigger in mysql, however in SQL Server I am a noob.

```
INSERT INTO sensores_tem_alarmes(idSensor,idAlarme,dataAlarme) VALUES (NEW.idSensor,@maxidAlarme,NOW());
set @comp=+1;


set @id_sensores_em_alerta=1;
SELECT MAX(id_sensores_em_alerta) into @id_sensores_em_alerta FROM sensores_em_alerta;
 INSERT INTO sensores_em_alerta(id_sensores_em_alerta, idSensor, idAlarme, data_registo, numerosensoresdisparados) VALUES (id_sensores_em_alerta,NEW.idSensor, @maxidAlarme, NOW(), @comp);
```

[image]

Comment: You have logic problem here `SELECT lim_inf_temp  from sensores where idSensor=idSensor`. The value `idSensor` is compared to itself, that is why it is always the same.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know that problem, but the big problem of all this, is that I do not know how to solve it: S 
Could he help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line like this:

```
DECLARE @temp decimal = (SELECT s.lim_inf_temp  from sensores s JOIN inserted i ON s.idSensor=i.idSensor )
```

Hope this is what you want as far as I can understand:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Alert ON registos AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @comp decimal = 0
DECLARE @id_sensores_em_alerta decimal
DECLARE @tempmin decimal = 0
DECLARE @current_max_idAlarme int = (SELECT MAX(IdAlarme) FROM alarmes)
DECLARE @maxidAlarme int
DECLARE @temp decimal = (SELECT s.lim_inf_temp  from sensores s JOIN inserted i ON s.idSensor=i.idSensor )


-- Insert into alarmes from the inserted rows if temperature less than tempmin
INSERT alarmes (IdAlarme, descricao_alarme,data_criacao, idRegisto)
    SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.idRegisto) + @current_max_idAlarme, 'temp Error', GETDATE(), i.idRegisto
    FROM
inserted AS i
    WHERE
i.Temperatura < @temp

SET @maxidAlarme = (SELECT MAX(IdAlarme) FROM alarmes)

INSERT INTO sensores_tem_alarmes(idSensor,idAlarme,dataAlarme) 
SELECT i.idSensor, @maxidAlarme, GETDATE()
FROM inserted i
SET @comp += 1;

SET  @id_sensores_em_alerta = (SELECT MAX(id_sensores_em_alerta) FROM sensores_em_alerta)

INSERT INTO sensores_em_alerta(id_sensores_em_alerta, idSensor, idAlarme, data_registo, numerosensoresdisparados) 
SELECT ISNULL(@id_sensores_em_alerta, 1)+1, i.idSensor, @maxidAlarme, GETDATE(), @comp
FROM inserted i
```

END

Comment: It works. Very thanks Sir. Not wanting to abuse your kindness. Could you help me add these insert's to my trigger please? I'm so sorry.

INSERT INTO sensores_tem_alarmes(idSensor,idAlarme,dataAlarme) VALUES (NEW.idSensor,@ maxidAlarme,NOW());
set @ comp=+1;

set @ id_sensores_em_alerta=1;
SELECT MAX(id_sensores_em_alerta) into @ id_sensores_em_alerta FROM sensores_em_alerta;

Comment: INSERT INTO sensores_em_alerta(id_sensores_em_alerta, idSensor, idAlarme, data_registo, numerosensoresdisparados) VALUES (id_sensores_em_alerta,NEW.idSensor, @ maxidAlarme, NOW(), @ comp);

Comment: You have `IDENTITY` set on id columns?

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id_sensores_em_alerta', table 'sensores_em_alerta'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54293/discussion-between-andlev-and-user3320956).

Comment: thanks for the help. Seriously, thank you very much, but it gives error here: S

(ISNULL(SELECT MAX(id_sensores_em_alerta FROM sensores_em_alerta), 1)

Comment: Lost some `)`. Check now.

Comment: The trigger works. Very thanks :)
But give this error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_sensores_tem_alarmes'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'sensores_tem_alarmes'. The duplicate key value is (Sensor01)...I can put the table sensores_tem_alarmes without PK?it result?

Comment: You should drop primary key on this column. Add another column for id if it is needed.

Comment: and this??
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__sensores'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'sensores_em_alerta'. The duplicate key value is (1).

Comment: Forgot to increment `id_sensores_em_alerta`